# One variable name combining a static name + a variable name

Tags: r

What I would like is to have a variable like

```
testNewYork <- "EEUU"
```

but I would like to keep the "`test`" part static, and then have the "`NewYork`" part as a variable. For instance something like

```
test+(city) <- "EEUU"
```

So, then I can have a loop, where city could be `NewYork`, but then it could be other city

Comment: I don't know `r`, but dynamically naming variables like that is almost always poor practice. Use a dictionary/map instead.

Comment: +100 @Carcigenicate. "Magically" appearing variables in the global environment is a pretty non-intuitive side-effect. Create a new environment or list to store named entities.

Comment: Make a list called `test`, then create a list element name `"NewYork"` (or any other city) to contain something. `test = list(); test[["NewYork"]] = "EEUU"`. See [How do I make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for discussion and examples.

Comment: OMGosh @Gregor I had just used that same exact idiom for an answer.

Comment: @hrbrmstr it's almost as if it's the right way to do it! (Already upvoted your answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. Use a `list` or an `environment`:

```
test <- list()
test$NewYork <-  "ABCD"
test$SanFrancisco <-  "EFGH"
test$Houston <- "IJKL"

str(test)
## List of 3
##  $ NewYork     : chr "ABCD"
##  $ SanFrancisco: chr "EFGH"
##  $ Houston     : chr "IJKL"

test$NewYork
## [1] "ABCD"

test[["NewYork"]]
## [1] "ABCD"

test$Portland <- "MNOP"

str(test)
## List of 4
##  $ NewYork     : chr "ABCD"
##  $ SanFrancisco: chr "EFGH"
##  $ Houston     : chr "IJKL"
##  $ Portland    : chr "MNOP"
```

Comment: ...or even a named vector if all OP is assigning is single strings.

Comment: True. I'd like to know the use-case of the problem the OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You need `assign`. You can put this in a loop and change `city` in every loop -

```
city <- "NewYork"
assign(paste0("test", city), "EEUU")
```

Comment: This is formally right but conceptualy wrong, see the comments and answers above. (@hrbrmstr Not my downvote.)

Comment: @hrbrmstr yeah, surprised by the downvote. Only trying to answer OP's question. I usually refrain from advising posters unless I have detailed info on what they are trying to achieve. This post hardly has any details.