# assigning values of character vector to object

Tags: r

I have a character vector "x" that stores some values of the locations. When I run a while loop I get these locations

```
i <- 1
while (i < 5) {
    print(x[c(i)])
    i = i+1
}
```

Output is :

```
[1] "/SampleData/exp964/K8"
[1] "/SampleData/exp294/K9"
[1] "/SampleData/exp264/K3"
[1] "/SampleData/exp29/K1"
```

Now, what I want to do is to assign these outputs to an object something like this

```
s_1 = "/SampleData/exp964/K8"
s_2 = "/SampleData/exp294/K9"
s_3 = "/SampleData/exp264/K3"
s_4 = "/SampleData/exp29/K1"
```

so that I can point to any object or use it in my code just by using c(s(i))  or something like that.

Could someone please help me getting this wrkable.

Thank you

Comment: You don't want to do that. You can always just do `x[1]`, or you can create names, like `names(x) <- paste0("s_",1:5)`, and then do `x["s_1"]`.

Comment: @joran Thank you :)

Comment: similar post - [One variable name combining a static name + a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250691/one-variable-name-combining-a-static-name-a-variable-name/53250742#comment93386535_53250742)

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
x <- c("/SampleData/exp964/K8", "/SampleData/exp294/K9", "/SampleData/exp264/K3", "/SampleData/exp29/K1")
```

you don't need to do any more assignments. Just as in your loop, you may use, e.g.,

```
x[2]
# "/SampleData/exp294/K9"
```

to get those values. Having a *vector* of values rather than several separate variables is much more convenient, flexible, and a better practice.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes a simple soluton is the need of the hour while we keep looking for the complicated ways